# Pagination links on top of the page, before actual script

Tags: php

I have a simple navigation php script which works ok.
The only problem is that I need to find a way to display the pagination links on top of the page instead of the bottom. 
So for me a newb, it seems impossible since I have to show the pagination links before the actual navigation variables are being declared.

Can this be done?

Here is the script:

```
<?
$numrows = '600';
$rowsperpage = 20;
$totalpages = ceil($numrows / $rowsperpage); 
if ($currentpage > $totalpages){ $currentpage = $totalpages; } 
if ($currentpage < 1){ $currentpage = 1; } 
$offset = ($currentpage - 1) * $rowsperpage; 

HERE I query the data from the table and basically fill in the page.

Now starts the pagination links:

$range = 3;
if ($currentpage > 1) {  
    echo '<a href="'.$site_current.'/'.$slug.'/">First</a>'; 
}
$prevpage = $currentpage - 1;   

echo '<a href="'.$site_current.'/'.$slug.'/'.$prevpage.'/">Previous</a>';

for ($x = ($currentpage - $range); $x < (($currentpage + $range) + 1); $x++) {   
    if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $totalpages)) {      
        if($x == $currentpage){ 
            echo '<span class="current">'.$x.'</span>'; 
        } else { 

            echo '<a href="'.$site_current.'/'.$slug.'/'.$x.'/">'.$x.'</a>';

        } 
    } 
}

if ($currentpage != $totalpages){  
    $nextpage = $currentpage + 1;    
    echo '<a href="'.$site_current.'/'.$slug.'/'.$nextpage.'/">Next</a>';   
    echo '<a href="'.$site_current.'/'.$slug.'/'.$totalpages.'/">Last</a>'; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Separate what you display from your logic.  Work out what what you want to display in variables before you echo anything. Then, when you have all the information you need, echo the results in the order that makes the most sense.

Comment: Why do you have `$numrows` quoted? It's a number. You work with it as a number. The quotes just make PHP cast to an integer each time you use it.

Comment: Instead of 600 there is a variable. Ty for the coments, just figured it out:) I can put the pagination links just under the offset and then start the actual mysql queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I do anything in PHP I do the following

```
<?php
    //Calculate anything I need for the page to be displayed

    //Build the html page and fill in variables where needed
?>
```

You may also want to look into frameworks like smarty that separate the logic from the template designs.  PHP is really a templating language in itself but I actually quite like using smarty.

Comment: Ty, you are right, it works... i have placed the pagination links just under $offset = ($currentpage - 1) * $rowsperpage; and then do my mysql rows foreach loop which displays the paginated data